# $S_n$ as a Coxeter group? (with Matsumoto's theorem)

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, symmetric-groups

I need to find a book in which basic $S_n$ theory is covered, mainly the part about Bruhat order, length of an element $w \in S_n$ and invariance modulo braid relations of the expressions $w=s_{i_1}\dots s_{i_k}$ (Matsumoto's theorem)

Are you aware of any good reference?

Comment: The things you mention here are usually discussed in connection with seeing $S_n$ as a Coxeter group, not a braid group (it is in fact not a braid group, but a quotient of a braid group).

Comment: Ken Brown's book "Buildings" has a lot of information, and is free online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I've heard it called Matsumoto's theorem, but there are quite a few references having this information. A classic is *Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups* by Humphreys, and a more recent one is *Combinatorics of Coxeter groups* by Bjorner and Brenti, which has quite a bit about $S_n$ (though most of the book works in a more general setting).

Comment: I was looking for a book/article/note specifically about $S_n$, isn't there anything like that? $\qquad$
(by the way, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsumoto%27s_theorem_(group_theory) )

Comment: Not familiar with anything like that, sorry.

Comment: +1: Bjorner and Brenti's coverage of these topics is very accessible. Matsumoto's theorem is theorem 3.3.1 in that book. They attribute the theorem to Tits. Geck and Pfeiffer's *Characters of Finite Coxeter Groups and Iwahori-Hecke Algebras* attribute it to Matsumoto. It is Theorem 1.2.2 in that book.